# Using Regex to replace groups in a String only replaces the last group

Tags: swift, regex, swift5

I have this string "[test1] AAAAAA [test2] BBBBB [test3]" and I'm trying to Regex all the keys wrapped in brackets `[test1]` with another string.

So my result would be: "ONE AAAAAA TWO BBBBB THREEE"

But, my regex is only replacing the very last key `[test3]`

> [test1] AAAAAA [test2] BBBBB [THREE]

**What am I doing wrong?**

*I know the bracket is still in my output, I haven't gotten to the part where I strip that out yet.*

```
let testString = "[test1] AAAAAA [test2] BBBBB [test3]"


extension String {
    func substring(from: Int, to: Int) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: to - from)
        return String(self[start ..< end])
    }
    
    func substring(range: NSRange) -> String {
        return substring(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
    }
}

let pattern = "\\[(.+?)\\]"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)

func replaceElements(_ original: String) -> String {

    var replaced = original
    
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: original.utf16.count)

    regex.enumerateMatches(in: original, options: [], range: range) { (results, flags, stop) in
        guard let results = results else { return }
        
        let range1 = results.range(at: 1)
        let key = original.substring(range: range1)
        
        if let value = swap(key: key) {
            replaced = original.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
        }
    }
    
    return replaced
}


func swap(key: String) -> String?{
    
    if key == "test1" {
        return "ONE"
    }
    
    if key == "test2" {
        return "TWO"
    }

    if key == "test3" {
        return "THREE"
    }
    
    return nil
}

print(replaceElements(testString))
```

Comment: Use `replaced = replaced.replacingOccurrences(of: original.substring(range: results.range(at: 0)), with: value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small mistake. Instead of assigning the "treated" string, you keep reassigning the *original* one with the current replacement:

```
// Instead of replaced = original.replacing...
replaced = replaced.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
```

Having said that, you can achieve exactly the same result with a minimal approach and avoid regex and ranges altogether. Something like this:

```
let testString = "[test1] AAAAAA [test2] BBBBB [test3]"

let keyMap = [
    "[test1]" : "ONE",
    "[test2]" : "TWO",
    "[test3]" : "THREE",
]

var output = testString

for (key, value) in keyMap {
    output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
}

print(output)
```

Comment: *exhales hales deeply*  Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed your updated answer with your, much easier, for my implementation, solution.  The RegEx version might help someone else though!